# GTA 5. Can you use sold cars in races

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, grand-theft-auto-online

If you customise a car and upgrade it, then sell it, will it be available to use in a race.

Answer (score 1):

No. Races use your personal vehicles. Since you sold the car, it doesn't get registered as a personal vehicle.